# How would the graph of such a function look like?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

If I have the function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ $g(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$.

How would I go about plotting its graph? Is there any software I can use? (no need for accuracy, just want the basic idea)

Comment: [wofram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bcos(x),sin(x)%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is the distance of $(\cos t,\sin t)$ from $(0,0)$?

To answer the software question, I'd recommend [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/).

Answer (score 0):

How do you graph $y=sin(x)$? You plug in some values ($sin(\pi/2)=1, sin(\pi)=0$ etc..) to get points in Cartesian system and approximately join these points to get the graph(most of it guessing). Just like these you plug in $t=0, t=-\pi/4, t=\pi/4$ etc... For example plugging $t=0$ you get a regular (x, y) point coordinate $x=sin(0)=0, y=cos(0)=1$. So make sure your graph passes through the point $(0, 1)$. Note in case of parametric functions there is also the concept **direction of the motion**. Find info about that in [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParametricEqn.aspx) and online graph plotter [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ksjcpazwa9).

Comment: What I am confused about is the codomain of my function being RxR. Do classic Cartesian coordinates work for this? Don't I need to do something like (y1,y2) for the vertical axis and x for the horizontal one? But then I could make a different graph only for this (y1, y2).

Comment: the g: R->RxR part means that it is a map from one real value to two real values , that is t -> x and y. Your coordinate system is the same old Cartesian system as you know (vertical is y, horizontal is x).

Comment: The only difference is that in y=f(x), if you have x you get y, or if you have y you might be able to get x. But in g(t) = (f(x), h(y)) you have t and you can get x and y, thus still the same result. t is not seen in graph, only the curve is.